# How to resample audio?

Tags: c++, math, audio

What’s the best algorithm to change sample rate of PCM audio?

The input is often `int16_t` at 44.1 kHz but can also be 32kHz or other frequency. The output I need is 32-bit `float` at 48 kHz. I’m proficient in SIMD intrinsics and guaranteed to have either NEON or AVX, so an algorithm based on float math is OK.

Do I need to implement [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) + inverse, or is there something less computationally expensive?

For instance, will cubic splines work for this use case, or they gonna introduce frequency artifacts?

Comment: You are correct in that you just need to interpolate. For 44.1 kHz to 48 kHz you will probably get away with linear interpolation, cubic splines would yield some smoother results. A Fourier transform is not required, this can be done entirely in the Time Domain

Comment: It depends on how close to Nyquist the signal content has. You could run sample data and compare errors from interpolation algos against a large, windowed sinc which will get everything even close to Nyquist. Pick the fastest with acceptable errors.

Comment: @doug I have no control over the audio data end users gonna play or record. I can and will test with commercial audio records and YouTube streams. Still, end users may have completely different sounds, I’d like the resampler to be not terribly bad even for 20kHz signals.

Comment: Oh dear. If you have any significant signal at 20kHz sampled at 44.1kHz then linear or spline interpolation is a non starter. You will need a windowed DFFT or relatively long windowed sinc FIR interpolator. That said, you won't find significant 20kHz on almost any recorded CDs for many reasons including reconstruction during playback. So you really need to know the actual spectrum you are dealing with,

Comment: @doug Do you happen to know how does OSX built-in mixer resamples? Professional software like CuBase?
I have limited budget, ideally I’d like to not waste time implementing multiple versions of that code. Do you think I should go with cubic splines, or FFT? Also, my performance budget for that is limited too, 50% of 1 ARM64 core at 1GHz. Do you think that’s enough for FFT+inverse, assuming the code is manually vectorized i.e.  mostly doing 4-wide vector FMA instructions?

Comment: Pragmatically, I think worrying about quality when the source is an mp3 YouTube stream isn't worth it. Cubic spline should be fine and a brick wall filter for anything approaching Nyquist will be more than adequate. If you are worried about re-inventing the wheel use FFMPEG. If you want to use macOS APIs, [look at Audio Toolbox Audio Converter Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_converter_services). If you want to learn about resampling, see the [DSP Stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resampling)

Comment: @fdcpp The source can be mp3 from youtube, but it can also be a software synthesizer or any other piece of software running on the device. Thanks for the comment, I’ll start with cubic splines then and see what gonna happen. Mostly because electricity i.e. battery charge. If possible, I’d like the mixer to consume less than 50% of CPU core even while resampling a couple of input streams. Algorithmically FFT is rather complex, unfortunately.

Comment: I'd go with a short sinc sequence FIR filter. An FFT is overkill. OTOH, a spline would be fine for most purposes. CD "Red Book" is quite old but in theory could have significant signal at 20 kHz.  But it rarely occurs. Data from MP3 should be fine with just a linear interpolation. I don't know what OSX uses so can't help there. I use a 10X windowed sinc and linear interp for variable rate conversions but it's for lab work and a bit overkill for what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, FFT is the requirement for good quality.

[This web site](https://src.infinitewave.ca/) has nice graphs of more than 100 pieces of software who are doing audio resampling. From a prior experience, I knew the professional software made by Steinberg is often doing the right things. The graphs on that web site agree, for Cubase 10 and Nuendo 11 these graphs are very good indeed.

Fortunately for me, pretty much the same quality is produced by ffmpeg 4.2.2 with [soxr](https://sourceforge.net/projects/soxr/) resampler. That particular resampling library comes with a good enough license, and the DLL is even available [as a package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=soxr&branch=edge&repo=&arch=aarch64) for my target OS.

I have integrated that library. While playing back 44.1 kHz wave file resampling in runtime into 48 kHz, my test program only consumes about 1% of CPU time (the CPU is quad code Allwinner A64 @ 1 GHz) so the performance is good despite the FFT.

Back to my original question, the algorithm implemented in that library is from the 2005 paper by Laurent de Soras “[The Quest For The Perfect Resampler](http://ldesoras.free.fr/doc/articles/resampler-en.pdf)”.

As written in the readme, it combines Julius O. Smith's `Bandlimited Interpolation' [technique](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/resample/resample.pdf) with FFT-based over-sampling. The math is rather complicated there. I was lucky to find that library as I would have wasted too much time trying to do something similar myself.